# Every quasi-compact scheme has a closed point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I know this question has been asked here before, but I have trouble understanding the following proof, taken from a Schwede's [write-up](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/schwede03.pdf).

[image]

I have underlined the bit I don't understand. In particular, I have no idea how we can conclude that $P_3$ is not in $U_2$. Didn't we pick $P_2$ to be any point in the closure of $P_1$? So, can someone explain rigorously why the point $P_3$, which is any point in the closure of $P_2$ (other than $P_2$, right?) ought not to be in $U_2$?

I know I am missing something obvious here, because this seems to be a common proof. Also, its probably topology that's giving me trouble here, so I will also tag it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $P_1$ is a closed point of $U_1$, we have $\overline{P_1} \cap U_1 = P_1$, where $\overline{P_1}$ denotes the closure of $\{P_1\}$ in $X$.

Since $P_2 \in \overline{P_1}$, which is a closed set, we have $\overline{P_2} \subseteq \overline{P_1}$.

Now, I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary, but maybe we're worried that, unlike $P_1$, $P_2$ might not be a closed point of $U_2$.  If not, though, we can replace it with one, because $\overline{P_2} \cap U_2$ is closed in $U$, and a closed set of an affine scheme contains a closed point.  Moreover, since each  point of $\overline{P_2} \cap U_2$ lies in $\overline{P_1}$, we could have chosen this point to being with.

Presumably we're not supposed to take $P_3$ to be $P_1$ or $P_2$, even though it doesn't technically say this.  (Maybe it's automatic that $P_1 \not \in \overline{P_2}$ for some reason I don't see immediately -- I'm having trouble picturing an example.)  Since $P_3 \in \overline{P_2}$, $P_3 \neq P_2$, and $\overline{P_2} \cap U_2 = P_2$, we have $P_3 \not \in U_2$, and similarly $P_3 \not \in U_1$.

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks a lot for your answer! It is more clear now. I think it is the part "$P_2$ is not necessarily a closed point of $U_{2}$" is precisely what confused me. In other words, I think the non-trivial step is indeed the reduction to that case. Let me think a little more about replacing $U_2$ by $\overline{P}_2\cap U_2$, and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: When you pick $P_{3}$ in $\overline{P_2}$, it is possible to make sure that $P_{3}\neq P_{2}$ (because $P_{2}$ is not closed in $X$). But how do you make sure that $P_{3}\neq P_{1}$? (This would follow if we can somehow show $P_{1}\notin\overline{P}_2$)

Comment: Well if the closure of P1 is just those two points then we're already done.

Comment: Ah, because then $P_{3}$ would be closed automatically.

Comment: I just posted a [follow up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361075/can-we-always-find-q-in-overline-p-with-p-notin-overline-q) concerning the parenthetical remark in your post. I think it is pretty interesting!

Comment: If $P_1\in \overline{P_2}$ then $\overline{P_1}=\overline{P_2}$ which, by going to the affine open, means $P_1=P_2$. This contradicts our choice of $P_2$.