# Can we always find $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$ with $p\notin \overline{\{q\}}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a quasiprojective scheme. Let $p\in X$ be a non-closed point, i.e. $\overline{\{p\}}\neq \{p\}$. Can we always find $q\in \overline{\{p\}}$ with $p\notin\overline{\{q\}}$?

Of course, if $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$, then immediately $\overline{\{q\}}\subseteq \overline{\{p\}}$. But this question asks something stronger.

**Motivation.** Answering this question would slightly simplify Daniel's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360731/49227) to my previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to assume quasi-projectivity. All schemes are *sober* topological spaces. This means that every irreducible closed subset has a unique generic point (i.e. a point whose closure is the subset). In particular, if $q\neq p$, then $\overline{\{p\}}\neq\overline{\{q\}}$. If $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$ is different from $p$ (which exists for $p$ not a closed point), it therefore must be that $p\notin\overline{\{q\}}$, since this containment would imply an equality of closures.

What this really uses is the weaker property of schemes being $T_0$-spaces, also known as Kolmogorov spaces (spaces for which, given $p\neq q$, there is an open neighborhood of one of the points which does not contain the other). In the above situation, $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$ means that every open neighborhood of $q$ contains $p$, so there must be a neighborhood of $p$ which does not contain $q$, and this means that $p$ is not in the closure of $\{q\}$.